# Fatal error: Uncaught Pecee\SimpleRouter\Exceptions\NotFoundHttpException: Route or method "post" not allowed

Tags: php, ajax, routes

The second problem is with the routing. I've registered correctly a post route in [Simple Router](https://github.com/skipperbent/simple-php-router) but if I call it to post some data using ajax, I will get always this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Pecee\SimpleRouter\Exceptions\NotFoundHttpException: Route "/event/add/" or method "post" not allowed.

This is how I've registered the routes, I've followed the documentation:

```
<?php

/* set the namespace for all controllers */
SimpleRouter::setDefaultNamespace('Controllers');

/* this will render the index */
SimpleRouter::get('/', 'Controller@index');

/* this will render the regeistration form */
SimpleRouter::get('/signup', 'Controller@registration');

/* this route is called with ajax and work without problems */
SimpleRouter::post('/user/add', 'UserController@addUser');

/* also this route is called by ajax and works too */
SimpleRouter::post('/user/verify', 'UserController@validateUser');

/* this route will render a form */
SimpleRouter::get('/event/create', 'Controller@eventForm');

/* this is the route that will generate the error message, but will work and send data to the controller */
SimpleRouter::form('/event/add', 'EventsController@addEvent');

/* this route works without problems */
SimpleRouter::get('/search/event/{id}', 'EventsController@searchEvent');

/* Start the routing */
SimpleRouter::start();

?>
```

JS code:

```
$('#save-event').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#event-form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'add',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function(){},
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

The data passed with ajax to `/event/add` are saved correctly inside the database, this is strange.
Any help to fix the issue will be appreciated

Comment: try without the trailing slash

Comment: I need to test your suggestion, In my ajax call, I use only the `add` as the url, this because the script is executed from the `/event/create` view, so the url contain already the `/event/` route.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is posting to the url `/event/add/` <- Notice the trailing slash.

You can correct this by changing your code to post to `/event/add`.

Comment: No, I'm posting to the url withou the trail slash, see the question

Comment: Can you post your javascript code then? Somewhere the trailing slash is being added.